# Parallel ssis execution

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have about 112 packages. Actually these packages are executing sequentially using package master.

I need to execute these packages parallel. I create package master and add all these packages manually but it's not easy for support and maintenance. Is there a way or an idea how to extract all packages names from table parameter for example, then execute them in parallel automatically and not add packages manually?

Comment: You could use SQL to kick off your packages, but you are still maintaining something (in this case a table).

Comment: @KeithL could you please explain more?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

You can run an execute SQL in a foreach loop (in SSIS) or you can run in a CURSOR in SSMS.

This is a assuming you deploy to SSISDB.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
        @package_name=N'[Package Name].dtsx'
        , @project_name=N'[ProjectName]'
        , @folder_name=N'[FolderName]'
        , @use32bitruntime=False
        , @reference_id=NULL
        , @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT

    -- Execute the package
    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
END
```

You can also add parameters if needed.

This is a good article about different applications: https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/11/28/a-better-way-to-execute-ssis-packages-with-t-sql/

**Note: The default is run async**

Comment: I need to execute the packages in parallel. I already use foreach loop to execute the packages sequentially.

Comment: If this is executed inside a foreach loop it will run async (in parallel) and start them all.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS does not have support for such scenario out of the box. There are some approaches to do this, but with some limitations.

### Async Out of main process Execution

The approach described in @KeithL's answer is pretty straightforward, but has certain drawbacks:

- Each child package started in its own execution. You can end up having started all 112 packages experiencing resource shortage. SSIS Engine does not orchestrate overall resources in this case.
- Package started in its own execution. It does not inherit parent package params or connection managers. You have to set it anew from calling SQL code or environment variable mappings.
- From support point of view - you get 113 independent executions in the SSIS log. Not easy to link it especially on high-load system.

### In-process execution

Alternative - handle this parallel invocation scenario with SSIS Task **Package Run**. From SSIS design approach, you have to describe all packages being run in the master package. Constructing the master package by hand is not practical, so you can use [BIML](https://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress). BIML can build your master package based on some metadata; it is really powerful but requires learning and practice.

### Limited parallel execution

Create a For Loop block in SSIS with control variable `i` and loop exist condition `i==0`. In the block - set `i = select count(*) from <package_queue> with (updlock, readpast)` with SQL Task and process to dummy Expression Task if `i==0`; this is a loop break path. Otherwise, with path condition `i>0` read one line from the package queue removing if from the queue, and start selected package execution with **Package Run** task.

Quite complex, but this is not the end of the story. Make several copies of the Copy Loop block in the SSIS Master package. Thus you will get a framework for concurrent execution  with limited concurrency.